# How to remove neighboring country names from the map?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

So, I have been working to style my map. But, stepped on a hitch back, such as to how to remove the neighbouring country name. So, my focus of work is only on INDIA. Also, how to not let map zoom out after INDIA boundaries because it now zooms out all the way.

For refrence see img

[home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1jmL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps has a styling wizard where it's easy to customize your map, I found the `administrative.country` property and set `visibility off` in styler.

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Above link will help.